# Best Esperanto for the "hot news perfect"

Tags: translation

The "hot news perfect" is the past tense for very recent events, languages tend not to have a synthetic form for it, but they do have standard constructions, in English: *I have just arrived* or in Hiberno-English: *I'm after arriving* tracking the Irish *Táim tar eis teacht*. French is similar to English: *Je viens d'arriver*.

What is the equivalent Esperanto?

Comment: I've never heard this term before. I googled it just now and saw a couple of hits talking about the '"hot news" use of the present perfect.'

Comment: I know the term from [https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/the-hot-news-or-after-perfect-in-irish-english/] which discusses the Hiberno-English construction, but it isn't only found there. It is true that the present perfect is often used for the recent past in English, but certainly isn't for Esperanto.

Comment: Fixed link: https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/the-hot-news-or-after-perfect-in-irish-english/ @conor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Esperanto there is the word "ĵus".

*I have just arrived.* = *Mi ĵus alvenis.*